# I want to send FCMToken into URL in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I develop the app into webview. and configured firebase push notification successfully. messages are delivering fine.

But Now I want Device token into URL. by which I can send msg according to the token.

I write this code in Appdelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.map {String (format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
    print("Token : \(token)")
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    preferences.setValue(token, forKey: "token")
    preferences.synchronize()
}

//Changes

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    error: Error) {
    // Try again later.
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    //Saving fcmToken to pass to the url

    //Bhaskar Changes

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    preferences.setValue(fcmToken, forKey: "token")
    preferences.synchronize()
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Message Data", remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

and this code in Viewcontroller.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Retrieving the fcmToken
    let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
    let token = prefs.string(forKey: "token")
    //?token= \(token as Optional)&device=ios
    print("Token accessed : \(String(describing: token))")
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://instaglamexpress.com/app/customer/?device=ios&token=\(String(describing: token))")!))

}
```

But everytime when I run the program. token is not storing into the token variable. it is showing "nil".

Am I following the right procedure.??

Please help me with the actual solution.

Comment: Are you sure `didReceiveRegistrationToken` actually called?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to add `Messaging.messaging().delegate = self` in this way `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)` will never be called.